# ANTLR4 Semantic Predicates that is Context Dependent Does Not Work

Tags: antlr4

I am parsing a C++ like declaration with this scaled down grammar (many details removed to make it a fully working example). It fails to work mysteriously (at least to me). Is it related to the use of context dependent predicate? If yes, what is the proper way to implement the "counting the number of child nodes logic"?

```
grammar CPPProcessor;

cppCompilationUnit : decl_specifier_seq? init_declarator* ';'  EOF;

init_declarator:     declarator initializer?;
declarator:  identifier;
initializer: '=0';

decl_specifier_seq
  locals [int cnt=0]
    @init {  $cnt=0;    }
: decl_specifier+ ;
decl_specifier :   @init {    System.out.println($decl_specifier_seq::cnt);  }
    'const'
  | {$decl_specifier_seq::cnt < 1}? type_specifier {$decl_specifier_seq::cnt += 1;}  ;
type_specifier:  identifier ; 
identifier:IDENTIFIER;
CRLF: '\r'? '\n' -> channel(2);
WS: [ \t\f]+    -> channel(1);
IDENTIFIER:[_a-zA-Z] [0-9_a-zA-Z]* ;
```

**I need to implement the standard C++ rule that no more than 1 `type_specifier` is allowed under an `decl_specifier_seq`**.

Semantic predicate before `type_specifier` seems to be the solution.  And the count is naturally declared as a local variable in `decl_specifier_seq` since nested `decl_specifier_seq` are possible.

But it seems that a context dependent semantic predicate like the one I used will produce incorrect parsing i.e. a semantic predicate that references $attributes. First an input file with correct result (to illustrate what a normal parse tree looks like):

```
int t=0;
```

and the parse tree:

[image]

But, an input without the '=0' to aid the parsing

```
int t;
```

[image]

```
0
1
line 1:4 no viable alternative at input 't'
1
```

the parsing failed with the 'no viable alternative' error (the numbers printed in the console is debug print of the `$decl_specifier_cnt::cnt` value as a verification of the test condition). i.e. the semantic predicate cannot prevent the `t` from being parsed as `type_specifier` and `t` is no longer considered a `init_declarator`. What is the problem here? Is it because a context dependent predicate having `$decl_specifier_seq::cnt` is used?

Does it mean context dependent predicate cannot be used to implement "counting the number of child nodes" logic?

EDIT

I tried new versions whose predicate uses member variable instead of the `$decl_specifier_seq::cnt` and surprisingly the grammar now works proving that the Context Dependent predicate did cause the previous grammar to fail:

```
....
@parser::members {
  public int cnt=0;
}
decl_specifier
  @init {System.out.println("cnt:"+cnt);  }
: 
    'const'
  | {cnt<1 }? type_specifier {cnt++;}  ;
```

A normal parse tree is resulted:

[image]

This gives rise to the question of how to support nested rule if we must use member variables to replace the local variables to avoid context sensitive predicates?

And a weird result is that if I add a `/*$ctx*/` after the predicate, it fails again:

```
decl_specifier
  @init {System.out.println("cnt:"+cnt);  }
: 
    'const'
  | {cnt<1 /*$ctx*/ }? type_specifier {cnt++;}  ;
```

[image]

```
line 1:4 no viable alternative at input 't'
```

The parsing failed with `no viable alternative`. Why the `/*$ctx*/` causes the parsing to fail like when `$decl_specifier_seq::cnt` is used although the actual logic uses a member variable only?
And, without the `/*$ctx*/`, another issue related to the predicate called before @init block appears([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571210/antlr4-semantic-predicate-called-before-init))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR 4 evaluates semantic predicates in two cases.

1. The generated code evaluates a semantic predicate during parsing, and throws an exception of the evaluation returns false. All predicates traversed during parsing are evaluated in this way, including context-dependent predicates and predicates which do not appear at the left side of a decision.
2. The prediction method evaluates predicates in order to make correct decisions during parsing. In this case, predicates which appear anywhere other than the left edge of the decision being evaluated are assumed to return true (i.e. they are ignored). In addition, context-dependent predicates are only evaluated if the context data is available. The prediction algorithm will not create context structures that were not already provided by the parsing code. If a context-dependent predicate is encountered during prediction and no context is available, the predicate is assumed to return true (i.e. it is ignored for that decision).

The code generator does not evaluate the semantics of the target language, so it has no way to know that `$ctx` is semantically irrelevant when it appears in `/*$ctx*/`. Both cases result in the predicate being treated as context-dependent.

Comment: "If a context-dependent predicate is encountered during prediction and no context is available, the predicate is assumed to return true", will this cause incorrect parsing when the context information REALLY is needed for making the right decision? e.g. a predicate that implement the logic that ignore a rule if some previous rules have been matched so that the prediction must evaluate the context sensitive predicate in order to make the right prediction.

Comment: @JavaMan it will cause the prediction algorithm to see an ambiguity instead of a single viable alternative based on the result of the predicate was evaluated. In that case, prediction falls back to choosing the first alternative, whether or not the alternative is allowed by the predicate. Many times this results in a correct parse tree, but for some grammars it will not. The difficulty in resolving this problem is exacerbated by ANTLR 4's exceptional support for unbounded lookahead during prediction.

Comment: @JavaMan For a language with syntactic ambiguities like C++, you may need to modify the core algorithms before you are able to construct a usable parse tree (or possibly a parse forest, which is one of the techniques GoWorks relies on).