# What could be a reason for `_localctx` being null in an antlr4 semantic predicate?

Tags: grammar, antlr4, semantics, predicate, rule

I'm using list labels to gather tokens and semantic predicates to validate sequences in my parser grammar. E.g.

```
line
:
    (text+=WORD | text+=NUMBER)+ ((BLANK | SKIP)+ (text+=WORD | text+=NUMBER)+)+ 
    {Parser.validateContext(_localctx)}? 
    (BLANK | SKIP)*
;
```

where

```
WORD: [\u0021-\u002F\u003A-\u007E]+; // printable ASCII characters (excluding SP and numbers)
NUMBER: [\u0030-\u0039]+; // printable ASCII number characters
BLANK: '\u0020';
SKIP: '\u0020\u0020' | '\t'; // two SPs or a HT symbol
```

The part of `Parser.validateContext` used to validate the `line` rule would be implemented like this

```
private static final boolean validateContext(ParserRuleContext context) {
   //.. other contexts
   if(context instanceof LineContext) 
       return "<reference-sequence>".equals(Parser.joinTokens(((LineContext) context).text, " "));
   return false;}
```

where `Parser.joinTokens` is defined as

```
private static String  joinTokens(java.util.List<org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token> tokens, String delimiter) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0, n;
    if((n = tokens.size()) == 0) return "";
    builder.append(tokens.get(0).getText());
    while(++i < n) builder.append(delimiter + tokens.get(i).getText());
    return builder.toString();}
```

Both are put in a `@parser::members` clause a the beginning of the grammar file.

---

My problem is this: sometimes the `_localctx` reference is `null` and I receive "no viable alternative" errors. These are probably caused because the failing predicate guards the respective rule and no alternative is given.

Is there a reason–potentially an error on my part–why `_localctx` would be `null`?

---

**UPDATE:** The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580735/antlr4-semantic-predicates-that-is-context-dependent-does-not-work?rq=1) seems to suggest that semantic predicates are also called during prediction. Maybe during prediction no context is created and `_localctx` is set to `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of `_localctx` in a predicate are not defined. Allowable behavior includes, but is not limited to the following (and may change during any release):

1. Failing to compile (no identifier with that name)
2. Using the wrong context object
3. Not having a context object (null)

To reference the context of the current rule from within a predicate, you need to use `$ctx` instead.

Note that the same applies for rule parameters, locals, and/or return values which are used in a predicate. For example, the parameter `a` cannot be referenced as `a`, but must instead be `$a`.